# Best practice submit form with nested components vuejs

Tags: forms, vue.js

I'm working on a call tender project in VueJs.

I have a page to create or update call tender. To do this, I have a form with :

1. classic form input
2. a table with call tender line (see 4), i can add row with a product search component (see 3)

I would like to know what is the pratice to send a new call tender to my api with the row inside the table.

[image]

Thank for your reply.
Valentin

Answer (score 0):

You don't need [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) for that:

- Your entire state must reside in 1
- Your state must be passed ***down*** to sub components via [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props)
- Your state updates must be passed ***up*** to parent components via [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)
- You don't need to pass up updates from the searched value to 1 because only 2 cares about it

Note that the [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-model) directive does the two at the same time, since

```html
<Child v-model="x"/>
```

is an alias for

```html
<Child :value="x" @input="x = $event"/>
```

All in all in should look similar to:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Three = {
  template: `<input :value="search" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" placeholder="search">`,
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
    }
  }
};

const Four = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-for="product of value">
        <template v-if="product.name.includes(search)">
          {{ product.name }}
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="product.chosen">
          <input type="number" v-model="product.quantity">
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['search', 'value'],
};

const Two = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <Three v-model="search"/>
      <Four v-model="value.products" :search="search"/>
    </div>
  `,
  components: { Three, Four },
  props: ['value'],
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
    };
  },
};

const One = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <input placeholder="title" v-model="value.title">
      <input type="date" v-model="value.date">
      <textarea placeholder="comment" v-model="value.comment"></textarea>
      <Two v-model="value"/>
      <hr>
      <pre>form value is currently {{ value }}</pre>
    </div>
  `,
  components: { Two },
  data() {
    return {
      value: {
        title: '',
        date: undefined,
        comment: '',
        products: [
          { name: 'screwdriver', chosen: false, quantity: 0 },
          { name: 'lawnmover', chosen: false, quantity: 0 },
          { name: 'car', chosen: false, quantity: 0 },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: (h) => h(One),
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```